# jQuery Ajax form submit, empty return

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

[here is my script](http://mihalko.eu/script/)
I am playing with jQuery Ajax form submit, without success. All I got to my ajax query is an empty result. You can check my code from the source. I don't copy it here, because it is long, I hope it's not problem.

[JS](http://mihalko.eu/script/assets/js/forms.js)

I am trying to get response from send.php.

PHP code is simple:

```
return $_POST['field2'].$_POST['field1'].$_POST['m'];
```

Comment: You need to echo the data from your PHP script, not return it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the PHP code, Instead of `return` use `echo`.

```
echo $_POST['field2'].$_POST['field1'].$_POST['m'];
```

`return` should only be used in a function to return a variable while `echo` can actually print the string for use by JS.